# Defining value other than 0 or 1 for HeavidSideTheta function

Tags: functions

HeavisideTheta function always gives 0 or 1. I wonder if this is possible to define my own value for the HeavisideTheta function other than 0 and 1, say 0.5, only for a specific notebook. Also, how to remove that specific value whenever I want and return its default value 0 or 1. Thanks!

Example:

For the following function,

HeavidsideTheta[0.5-x]

I want

HeavidsideTheta[0.5-x] = 1 when x < 0.5

and

HeavidsideTheta[0.5-x] = 1 when x >= 0.5

Note: This function is a part of other functions of "x" where integrals are involved.

Comment: This may be obvious but you can multiply it by any number or function you like to give what you need. You could write a function  `f[x_]:= 0.5 HeavisideTheta[x]`

Comment: Please see above example

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
moh[x__] := (1/2)*HeavisideTheta @@ {x}
```

Regarding your example, just reverse the sign, multiply the 'amplitude' and add the minimum:

```
moh[x__] := 1/2 + (1/2)*HeavisideTheta @@ {-x}
Plot[{moh[t - 1/2]}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

You can achieve the same thing by simply adding various step functions: `(1/2)*UnitStep[t - 1/2] + UnitStep[-(t - 1/2)]`.

Comment: Please see the above example

Comment: The line corresponding to -1 should correspond to 1 and the other should 0.5. I don't need the -1 part. Only 1 and 0.5 is required.

Comment: sorry, the first line to 1 and 2nd to 0.5

Comment: Now it worked. Thanks, Shin Kim!!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = .5;
b = 3;
c = 2;
Plot[a + (b - a)*HeavisideTheta[x - c], {x, -5, 8}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Clip` command, I show two variations using the 2nd and 3rd argument of the function:

```
Plot[{
  Clip[HeavisideTheta[0.5 - x], {0.3, 0.8}]
  , Clip[HeavisideTheta[0.5 - x], {0.3, 0.8}, {2, 4}]
  }
 , {x, -2, 2}
 , PlotRange -> {-0.2, 4.2}
 , Exclusions -> None
 ]
```

[image]